# How to Solve New line issues in CPP for javascript

Tags: javascript, c++

I am using

```
evaluateJavaScript(text)
```

function.
In my javascript I have a line like this

```
sugge = txt.split("\n");
```

In my Cpp program I have given like this

```
text ="sugge = txt.split('\n');";
```

My CPP program Complied without errors, but this script is not running in my webpage while cpp is evaluating javascript.

It is showing the error "unterminated string literal" in my browser console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are inseting a new line character in the middle of the string. To fix it you just need to [escape](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape) the backslash.

Change

```
text ="sugge = txt.split('\n');";
```

To

```
text ="sugge = txt.split('\\n');";
```